# Facebook Graph API: get link to users timeline doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to get the link to persons timeline who granted my app access.

So in the reference for the user (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/user) - i know it's outdatet version but it should still work - I can see the "link" field which gives me "A link to the person's Timeline" as the documentation says.

So when I am doing this, I get a link with the following format:

https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/YXNpZADpBWEVoMWtvWEVtYTM3RFBkS3dYQVdWMUNwMVRJMzNWeko4aF83eFpQU05jcXByTXJwVmFoS293a1FMSWlKNFpibTNmbFpGa04wOUh5bmlWc3ZAKV3ZAWeEt2MEFBYlljb2JWNHRMTDRSY1FybFNyNDNpU3cZD/
(it's a really long URL which is generated by facebook)

So far so good. But when I click on this URL which facebook gives me, I **always** get a Facebook Page with the content **"Sorry, this content isn't available right now"** (as you can see when you click on the link above).

I don't know what the problem is. Since a facebook profile isn't callable with the user-id I have this problem.

Does anybody know how to fix it and get a working link to the users timeline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ask for the new `user_link` permission now first, to be able to get a working link that will lead to a persons timeline.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_link

(The returned URLs seem to contain a cryptic token rather than an actual user id, so you should not store them for long-term usage, they will likely expire over time.)

Comment: I think you are right. Unfortunately you have to go through a review again to get this permission. But I will check it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From May 2018 developers should use **user_link** to get user profile link, but for using this field App should pass review and person grant you the new user_link permission.

For more info see:

- https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/05/01/facebook-login-updates-further-protect-privacy/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_link